# Drop Down List Value not passing to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

This question should be very simple.. I am trying to pass values in my drop down list in my view to the controller..  I'm not getting errors but it's sending a null value for that property. Please help..

My code is as follows:

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var list = new [] 

            { 
                new Room{ RoomID = 1, Building = "FAYARD HALL"},
                new Room{ RoomID = 2, Building = "WHATEVER HALL"},
                new Room{ RoomID = 3, Building = "TIME SQUARE"},
                new Room{ RoomID = 4, Building = "MISSISSIPPI"},
                new Room{ RoomID = 5, Building = "NEW YORK"},

            };


        var selectList = new SelectList(list,"RoomID", "Building");
        ViewData["BuildingList"] = selectList;  

        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Room/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Room room)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Rooms.Add(room);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(room);
    }
```

MY VIEW:

```
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Building, "Building")
    </div>
    <div>

        @Html.DropDownList("BuildingList", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Building)
    </div>
```

Please help...

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is your drop down populated? Given your code I think you need the following to do so:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Building, ViewData["BuildingList"])
```

ie. bind the selected value to the `Building` property of your `Room` and use the drop down list from your view model to populate the list.

I'm also not sure this is what your intention is. It seems a bit fishy that you are populating a drop down list with rooms and then based on the selection you are creating a new room.

**Edit**

Ok I'm going to make things a lot easier for you.

I'll start with your classes. Here is the room I am assuming you're working with:

```
public class Room
{
    public int RoomId { get; set; }
    public string Building { get; set; }
}
```

Now let's do something a bit better than using ViewData. I've created a view model for you. You will populate this with your select list and the item you choose in the view will be bound into the `SelectedRoomId` when you post the form.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public int SelectedRoomId { get; set; }
    public SelectList RoomOptions { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
private SelectList GetSelectList()
{
    var list = new[] 
    { 
        new Room { RoomId = 1, Building = "FAYARD HALL"},
        new Room { RoomId = 2, Building = "WHATEVER HALL"},
        new Room { RoomId = 3, Building = "TIME SQUARE"},
        new Room { RoomId = 4, Building = "MISSISSIPPI"},
        new Room { RoomId = 5, Building = "NEW YORK"}
    };

    return new SelectList(list, "RoomId", "Building");
}

public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel
    {
        RoomOptions = GetSelectList()
    };
    return View(viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Save here
        // create a new room using the SelectedOptionId in the viewModel
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    // repopulate the list if something failed
    viewModel.RoomOptions = GetSelectList();
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

**View**

```
@model PathToYourViewModel.ViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedRoomId, Model.RoomOptions, "-- select an option --")
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
};
```

Tried and tested. Good luck!

Comment: The List is populated in my view correctly.. For some reason it's showing a null value at the HttpPost Create method..  I"m creating a new room entity with the building value.. Thanks for your reply sir.

Comment: Sorry I've been away for a minute.. Your ideas has brought some in site to my problem.. Thanks again....

Answer (score 1):

The model binding takes place with help of the `names property` in mvc .

In your case the name of your control is `BuildingList`:

```
@Html.DropDownList("BuildingList", (SelectList)ViewData["BuildingList"])
```

Therefore at your controller Action will go as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
{
   var selectedValue = collection["BuildingList"];
}
```